# PHP dynamic name for object property

Tags: php, oop

Instead of using

```
$object->my_property
```

I want to do something like this

```
$object->"my_".$variable
```

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that while you can use dynamic variables, it is often preferable to be explicit. It makes refactoring later easier for one. Imagine searching for a property called "my_cat", you would not find that if it is declared dynamically.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use curly brackets like so:

```
$object->{'my_' . $variable}
```

Answer (score 9):

How about this:

```
$object->{"my_$variable"};
```

I suppose [this section](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) of PHP documentation might be helpful. In short, one can write any arbitrary expression within curly braces; its result (a string) become a name of property to be addressed. For example:

```
$x = new StdClass();
$x->s1 = 'def';

echo $x->{'s' . print("abc\n")};
// prints
// abc
// def
```

... yet usually is far more readable to store the result of this expression into a temporary variable (which, btw, can be given a meaningful name). Like this:

```
$x = new StdClass();
$x->s1 = 'def';

$someWeirdPropertyName = 's' . print("abc\n"); // becomes 's1'.
echo $x->$someWeirdPropertyName;
```

As you see, this approach makes curly braces not necessary AND gives a reader at least some description of what composes the property name. )

P.S. `print` is used just to illustrate the potential complexity of variable name expression; while this kind of code is commonly used in certification tests, it's a big 'no-no' to use such things in production. )

Comment: Thanks, if I could give two ticks you'd have one as well.